# Multiple Aggregates Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a few columns of data I am wanting to put into a Pivot table. This is what the data currently looks like once the following query is ran:

```
SELECT
    t.clinic,
    t.fiscal_year,
    t.total,
    n.new_pats,
    (t.total - n.new_pats) AS active
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    clinic,
    fiscal_year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) AS total
FROM transactions t
JOIN period p
    ON (t.date_entered BETWEEN p.period_start AND p.period_end)
GROUP BY clinic, fiscal_year) t
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    clinic,
    per.fiscal_year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) AS new_pats
FROM patient pat
JOIN period per
    ON (pat.first_visit_date BETWEEN per.period_start AND per.period_end)
GROUP BY clinic, fiscal_year) n
    ON (t.clinic = n.clinic AND t.fiscal_year = n.fiscal_year)
```

[image]

And I would like the data to be broken up by the three aggregates in their own rows and the years being the columns where it looks something like this:

[image]

This could also be broken into 3 separate columns per aggregate per year, but this is what I'm ideally aiming for. I haven't put together a Pivot table within SQL before and am at a loss. Is there a better way to go about formatting this data in the desired way?

Comment: Don't put it into an actual table. That would both be redundant (you're replicating existing data) and inflexible (what happens if, for example, the years change? Or even if just the data in your original tables changes). Instead, use a view or a stored procedure that "unpivots" your current query (either by actually unpivoting it or by reworking the current query to be, say, a union query for each clinic/year/aggregate) then pivot that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
SELECT clinic, 
       aggregate_field, 
       ISNULL([2009],0) AS [2009], 
       ISNULL([2010],0) AS [2010], 
       ISNULL([2016],0) AS [2016], 
       ISNULL([2017],0) AS [2017]
FROM   (SELECT clinic, 
               fiscal_year, 
               aggregate_field, 
               value 
        FROM   (
                ------- This part is your original query -----------------
                SELECT t.clinic, 
                       t.fiscal_year, 
                       t.total, 
                       n.new_pats, 
                       ( t.total - n.new_pats ) AS active 
                FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT clinic, 
                                        fiscal_year, 
                                        Count(DISTINCT patient_id) AS total 
                        FROM   transactions t 
                               JOIN period p 
                                 ON ( t.date_entered BETWEEN 
                                      p.period_start AND p.period_end ) 
                        GROUP  BY clinic, fiscal_year) t 
                       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT clinic, 
                                             per.fiscal_year, 
                                             Count(DISTINCT patient_id) AS new_pats 
                             FROM   patient pat 
                                    JOIN period per 
                                      ON ( pat.first_visit_date BETWEEN 
                                           per.period_start AND per.period_end ) 
                             GROUP  BY clinic, fiscal_year) n 
                         ON ( t.clinic = n.clinic 
                              AND t.fiscal_year = n.fiscal_year )
               -------------------------------------------------------------
               ) 
               unpivot_source 
               UNPIVOT ( value 
                       FOR aggregate_field IN (total, 
                                               new_pats, 
                                               active) ) unpivot_result) AS 
       pivot_source 
       PIVOT ( Max(value) 
             FOR fiscal_year IN ([2009], 
                                 [2010], 
                                 [2016], 
                                 [2017]) ) AS pivot_result 
ORDER  BY clinic, aggregate_field DESC
```

I've create a demo here http://rextester.com/MFHWV68715.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ActualData 
(
   Clinic varchar(50),
   fiscal_year int,
   total int,
   new_pats int,
   active int
)

INSERT INTO #ActualData VALUES ('A', 2016, 3538,1787,1751), ('A', 2017, 1218,373,845), ('B', 2009, 1,2,3), ('B', 2010, 1,2,3)

SELECT * FROM #ActualData ad

;WITH temps AS
   (
      SELECT Clinic, fiscal_year, aggregateF, Number FROM 
      (
         SELECT ad.Clinic, ad.fiscal_year, ad.total,ad.new_pats,ad.active FROM #ActualData ad
      ) src
      UNPIVOT
      (
         Number FOR aggregateF IN (total,new_pats ,active)
      ) unpvt
   )
SELECT Clinic, aggregateF, [2009],[2010],[2016],[2017]
FROM
(
   SELECT t.Clinic, t.aggregateF, t.fiscal_year, t.Number FROM temps t
) src
PIVOT
(
   MIN (Number) FOR fiscal_year IN ([2009],[2010],[2016],[2017])
) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.Clinic, pvt.aggregateF DESC

DROP TABLE #ActualData
```